# Not able to find Open Browser Keyword in SeleniumLibrary

Tags: selenium, robotframework

i am trying to write a simple webLogin Testcase in Roboframework, Below preconditions are done.

```
1.Installed all the necessary packages
2.Installed required SSH/SeleniumLibrary and Mozilla geckodriver
3.imported SSH and Selenium Library,
```

However I couldnt see any `Open Browser` keyword in `SeleniumLibrary`

Could anyone help me with this.

Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3 in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from selenium>=3.141.0->robotframework-seleniumlibrary)
Installing collected packages: robotframework-pythonlibcore, robotframework-seleniumlibrary

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqvLE.png

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to share code examples and error messages. They are rarely opened and your question may not receive the attention it otherwise would.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the IDE, RIDE.

You also opened an Issue in SeleniumLibrary project and I replied there that you should install the current Beta version of RIDE, which have that problem solved.

Comment: Thanks, i have upgraded the python and IDE now its working